# react js not serving static files when deployed using reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

have a reactjs app running under nginx perfectly fine. Requirements are to run this app under another website using **reverse-proxy**. My **nginx conf** says:

```
  location / {
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
 proxy_http_version 1.1;
 proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
 proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

 add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin website-2;
 add_header Access-Control-Expose-Headers Content-Length;
 add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers Range;
 }
```

However when I try to access this using **website-2/app** it gives an error saying:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “website2/static/js/2.2c5e110e.chunk.js”
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: "reactjs app running under nginx".  On what port is that nginx listening?

Comment: Please post the complete `server` block.